# How can I query for completed yaml releases using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, yaml, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I am using multi stage pipelines for creating ci,cd. Here I am not getting any releases under release tab.
So I am querying  all deployments using environment id.
See below link for getting deployment records by environment id.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environmentdeployment%20records/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Now I am looking for client api for above documentation.
example for getting classic releases through api `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi`.

```
var releases =  releaseClient.GetReleasesAsync(Project, releaseDefinitionId).Result;
```

Same way I am looking for any web api api available to get deployments using environment id.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **preview** version of assembly `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi`, and use [EnvironmentDeploymentExecutionRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.distributedtask.webapi.environmentdeploymentexecutionrecord?view=azure-devops-dotnet-preview) Class, this class is still under preview.

The code would look like example below:

```
 TaskAgentHttpClient edClient = connection.GetClient<TaskAgentHttpClient>();
 var project = "Git";
 int environmentid = 5;
 var Environmentdeployment = edClient.GetEnvironmentByIdAsync(project, environmentid).Result;
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Honestly, it is a shame some people ask a question and do not care about coming back with feedback. great job and answer, it is perhaps it is useful for me  saved me a few hours of work and research.